# Problema con fgets

Tags: c, fgets

Quiero diseñar una *mini* trivial de preguntas en C. La idea es bastante sencilla, el programa me hará 3 preguntas, cada pregunta tiene su respuesta correcta, si la cadena de caracteres digitada es exactamente igual que la respuesta correspondiente, el programa escriba que me suma puntos. Ej: La respuesta a la pregunta 1 es "Donatelo".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int compro;
    char rta[9];
    char rtaAPreguntaUno[9]="Donatelo";
    char rtaAPreguntaDos[10]="La piedad";
    printf("Introducir respuesta a pregunta 1: ");
    fgets(rta,9,stdin);
    if(strcmp(rta,rtaAPreguntaUno)==0){
        printf("+100");
    }
    printf("\nIntroducir respuesta a pregunta 2:");
    fgets(rta,10,stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

En primera instancia, el programa anda bien, me refiero a que si NO escribo `"Donatelo"` en la respuesta 1, pasa directo al segundo `printf`. El problema viene cuando **SI** escribo `"Donatelo"` como respuesta 1, me escribe +100 en la pantalla lo cual esta bien, pero después termina el programa sin siquiera esperar a que vuelva a introducir otro dato con el `fgets` (digamos como que lo ignora) ¿Como soluciono esto?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Esto **no** es un foro y tenemos consensuadas ciertas normas, la mayoría correctamente explicadas en [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Entre ellas, está el no formular mas de 1 pregunta por publicación. Esto haría muy difícil localizar la información para otros futuros usuarios con tu mismo problema.

Comment: Referente a tu pregunta: ¿ Que significa `termina el programa` ? ¿ Se cierra la ventana ? ¿ Estoy en lo cierto al asumir que estás en un sistema Windows ?

Comment: Perdón, tal vez no fui lo suficientemente claro. Mi pregunta es porque el programa termina sin pasar por el segundo fgets cuando se cumple el if. Si estoy en windows pero cuando programo lo hago desde un compilador web que tienen el system("pause") ya incluido.

Comment: En todo caso, me gustaría saber como realizarías tu el programa por ejemplo(si no puedes no hay problema). Recordar que lo tengo que hacer en C.

Comment: Mi pregunta era porque cabía la posibilidad de que se te cerrara la ventana del terminal **sin que llegaras a ver el mensaje**, aunque este si si mostrase. Pero, puesto que usas un entorno web, me dejas descolocado. Tendrás que esperar ayuda de otros usuarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > En primera instancia, el programa anda bien, me refiero a que si NO escribo "Donatelo" en la respuesta 1, pasa directo al segundo printf

Claro, si escribes `Donal`, la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) incluirá el salto de línea (porque no leyó la cantidad máxima de caracteres) en la cadena y por ende, en la siguiente invocación, `fgets` pausará el programa porque el búfer del teclado está limpio.

> > El problema viene cuando SI escribo "Donatelo" como respuesta 1, me escribe +100 en la pantalla lo cual esta bien, pero después termina el programa sin siquiera esperar a que vuelva a introducir otro dato con el fgets

Claro, como la función `fgets` leyó `8` caracteres, el salto de línea (producido por un `ENTER`) quedó en el búfer del teclado, por lo tanto, está sucio.

Así que la próxima vez que invoques a `fgets`, no pausará el programa a la espera de una cadena, porque encontró un caracter válido en el búfer, entonces lo lee y acaba el programa.

> > ¿Como soluciono esto?

Simplemente se debe verificar si en la última posición del arreglo no hay un salto de línea, si esta condición se cumple, limpiamos el búfer, de lo contrario, no.

**Solución:**

```c
int main()
{
    int compro;
    char rta[9];
    char rtaAPreguntaUno[9]="Donatelo";
    char rtaAPreguntaDos[10]="La piedad";
    printf("Introducir respuesta a pregunta 1: ");
    fgets(rta,9,stdin);
    if(strcmp(rta,rtaAPreguntaUno)==0){
        printf("+100");
    }
    if(rta[strlen(rta) - 1] != '\n')
    {
      //Limpiamos el búfer
      while(getchar() != '\n');
    }
    printf("\nIntroducir respuesta a pregunta 2:");
    fgets(rta,10,stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

**Actualización:**

La función [getchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) retorna el caracter leído del búfer de entrada estándar.

Entonces cuando el búfer del teclado quede con estos caracteres: `23\n`, lo que hará este código:

```c
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Es leer caracter por caracter hasta encontrar un salto de línea en el búfer.

En este caso, la función `getchar()` se invocará tres veces y esto se debe porque necesita leer estos caracteres:

```c
2
3
\n
```

Con esto logramos vaciar el búfer para que no quedé ningún caracter.

> > ¿No existe una funcion ya definida en alguna biblioteca para ahorrarse esto?

En C lamentablemente no existe tal función. Muchas personas usan la rutina [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) para limpiar el búfer del teclado, pero no se recomienda, ya que no se asegura que siempre funcione.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una función llamada `emptyBuf` y agregar todo el código ahí:

```c
/* 
   El parámetro `str` simplemente guardará la 
   dirección de memoria del primer caracter de 
   un arreglo de `char`.

   El "const char*" indica que no podemos usar 
   el puntero para modificar alguna dirección de 
   memoria perteneciente al arreglo.

   Es decir, si hago esto: str[1] = 'a'; --> 
   Error de compilación

   Esto básicamente nos sirve para indicar la 
   intención del parámetro y saber que
   en ningún momento modificará el 
   contenido de una dirección de memoria.
*/
void emptyBuf(const char* str)
{
    if(str[strlen(str) - 1] != '\n')
    {
      //Limpiamos el búfer
      while(getchar() != '\n');
    }
}
```

Posteriormente, invocamos la función de esta forma:

```c
int main()
{
    int compro;
    char rta[9];
    char rtaAPreguntaUno[9]="Donatelo";
    char rtaAPreguntaDos[10]="La piedad";
    printf("Introducir respuesta a pregunta 1: ");
    fgets(rta,9,stdin);
    if(strcmp(rta,rtaAPreguntaUno)==0){
        printf("+100");
    }
    emptyBuf(rta);
    printf("\nIntroducir respuesta a pregunta 2:");
    fgets(rta,10,stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Y de este modo, puedes reutilizar código.

Comment: Sos un dios amigo. Entonces para ver si entendí, perdón, empece a estudiar hace 1 mes, ni siquiera hemos visto vectores, a mi solo me gusta adelantarme, lo que estaba pasando era básicamente que el segundo fgets me leía un salto de linea provocado por un ENTER que quedo en ese "buffer", que entiendo que es una memoria del teclado o algo así, la naturaleza del fgets hace que se frena cuando encuentra un salto de linea y por eso me leia ese \n y terminaba. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: @Leandro Así es. La función fgets dejará de leer hasta llegar el tamaño máximo que le pasaste. En tu caso, al ingresar `Donatelo`, quedó el `\n` en el búfer, entonces fgets lo tomo como válido. Ahora imaginate si ingreso Donatelo2323, el búfer queda con `2323\n`, entonces al ejecutarse el siguiente fgets, no pausará el programa, porque el búfer ya tiene caracteres. Esa es la razón del porque debes limpiar el búfer del teclado.

Comment: Sos un dios amigo, te lo digo de nuevo jaja, muchísimas gracias. Por ultimo, tristemente estoy buscando en Internet pero tengo problemas para entender esa limpieza a la memoria del teclado¿Como es que la hiciste exactamente?¿No existe una funcion ya definida en alguna biblioteca para ahorrarse esto?

Comment: @Leandro He editado mi respuesta para aclarar dudas.

Comment: Se lo ve mucho mejor así la verdad, tristemente todavía no aprendí a definir funciones, sin embargo creo entender lo que hiciste, lo único que le doy vueltas es a los parámetros que le pusiste a la función(const char*str). De igual manera me solucionaste todo, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @Leandro Me da gusto que hayas entendido. He editado la respuesta donde explico en comentarios sobre el porque usé el parámetro `const char*`. De igual manera, si tienes dudas sobre esto, puedes crear otra pregunta relacionado a ello. Si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides de aceptarla como la "correcta". ¡Saludos!